# KVM and docking station solution for Desktop and Laptop

Tags: desktop, kvm, 4k, docking-stations

I have a desktop PC and a Thinkpad laptop which I would like to be able to connect to the same monitors, keyboard and mouse. The monitors will both be Philips 328P6VJEB (4K). I already have a docking station for the Thinkpad. What I would like to do is connect the desktop and docking station to the KVM, and when using the laptop, just plug the laptop into the docking station. Is there a KVM that I can use that will allow me to do this? Or is there another solution?